# How to give custom non-power-of-2 values to align directive of NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, memory-alignment

Code snippet of `lab1.s`:

```
2376  db 0xf2
2377  align 0x3A00
2378  tss0.0:
2379 ; TSS for default code when Test starts
2380  dd 0x0
2381  dd 0x1000
2382  dd 0x50
2383  dd 0x1000
```

When I try to assemble :

`nasm  -felf lab1.s`

I get the following error:

`` lab1.s:2377: error: segment alignment `0x3A00' is not power of two ``

**Question:**
Is it possible to give this specific value `0x3A00` to the `align` directive in some other way?

PS: I have not written this file but got it from elsewhere.

Comment: You could do padding using `TIMES` directive.

Comment: What do you expect `align 0x3A00` to do?

Comment: @fuz Honestly, I do not know. Like I said I just got it from someone and want to get a working binary out of this which will be used later.

Comment: @sweetpoision If you don't know what it does, that's the first thing you need to figure out.  I can't help you when you don't even know what you want.

Comment: Maybe you want to emit padding until you reach the address `0x3a00`?  That's more like `org`, not `align`, but `org` in NASM doesn't work that way either.  See https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdo13.html#section-13.1.3

Comment: using nasm v2.08 solved the problem.